# Query to group inner join rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 tables: Projects and custom_values which are linked by the project id.
I did this inner join query

```
SELECT custom_values.customized_id ,custom_values.custom_field_id,
custom_values.value FROM projects INNER JOIN custom_values ON    
projects.id=custom_values.customized_id order by custom_values.customized_id asc
```

You will find the responce of this query in the file joined.
[image]

I want to know if there is a way to group those rows by customized_id field.
By the way I tried Group by but it doesn't work

Comment: by group, what do you actually mean?

Comment: They look grouped to me !

Comment: but with this i have to make a backend code to make an object by rows which have the same customized_id

Comment: Try "GROUP BY custom_field_id"

Comment: @GajjarParth try not to give bad advices like that

Comment: Please share a sample dataset and expected result set. It's not clear what you want to get as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want group you need  a aggregation function eg (max, min group_concat) and group by , if you want all the values related  to a customized_id on a row you could use group_concat eg:

```
SELECT custom_values.customized_id 
  ,group_concat(custom_values.value )
FROM projects 
INNER JOIN custom_values ON projects.id=custom_values.customized_id 
GROUP BY custom_values.customized_id 
order by custom_values.customized_id asc
```